# How to scroll down the bootstrap modal when it jump out the visible area?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a long modal that jump out the visible area on smartphone.

I tried to search over Stackoverflow, but there is nothing about it.

Comment: Don't use Bootstrap. It forces bad design/coding practices. It's better to roll your own implementation - the right way. Try changing the background attribute of the modal to `position: absolute;` instead of `background-position: fixed;`.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"? If a Bootstrap 3 modal is too tall/long to fit onscreen, you'll still be able to scroll it.

Comment: @Aeron You mean with regard to using specific Bootstrap class names in your HTML, or..?

Comment: I just mean in general. Ive just spent the last 4 weeks rewriting a major site that was originally built with Bootstrap and I can tell you that it has been the biggest pain in the ass. In the end it was easier for me to rewrite the whole site on my own and it is now even easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms you need to set a max height or height on the modal body element/div then you can set the overflow-y :auto on the body contents. You should then get a scrollable section inside your modal.

If you wrap your max-height settings in a media query then you can control the break points at which you start to see scrolling for each size of screen.